# Unknown ACL condition/modifier in in EXIM configuration for Rspamd

Tags: ubuntu, exim, spam-filter

I am trying to configure EXIM to use Rspamd as a spam filter. I am running Exim version 4.87 and installed Rpsam from the repositories using `apt-get` as explained [here](https://rspamd.com/downloads.html). Then I added the suggested configuration from the [Rspamd documentation](https://rspamd.com/doc/integration.html) to my config file:

```
begin acl

# configure Rspamd
# Please note the variant parameter
spamd_address = 127.0.0.1 11333 variant=rspamd   # error occurs here

acl_smtp_data = acl_check_spam

acl_check_spam:
  # do not scan messages submitted from our own hosts
  accept hosts = +relay_from_hosts

  # do not scan messages from submission port
  accept condition = ${if eq{$interface_port}{587}}

  # skip scanning for authenticated users
  accept authenticated = *

  # add spam-score and spam-report header when told by rspamd
  warn  spam       = nobody:true
        condition  = ${if eq{$spam_action}{add header}}
        add_header = X-Spam-Score: $spam_score ($spam_bar)
        add_header = X-Spam-Report: $spam_report

  # use greylisting available in rspamd v1.3+
  defer message    = Please try again later
        condition  = ${if eq{$spam_action}{soft reject}}

  deny  message    = Message discarded as high-probability spam
        condition  = ${if eq{$spam_action}{reject}}

  accept
```

When I try to restart Exim I get the following error message:

```
error in ACL: unknown ACL condition/modifier in "spamd_address = 127.0.0.1 11333 variant=rspamd"
```

Which refers to the 4th line of the config code I posted above: `spamd_address = 127.0.0.1 11333 variant=rspamd`. I found the exact same line in the [official Exim documentation](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-content_scanning_at_acl_time.html). So it should work. Did anyone encounter that problem before, when configuring Exim to use Rspamd?

I am using Ubuntu:

```
$ uname -a
Linux calais 4.4.0-36-generic #55-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 11 18:01:55 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place `spamd_address = 127.0.0.1 11333 variant=rspamd` directive outside the ACL section. In general it should be placed at the beginning of config before ACLs, services, routers and transports are defined.

Comment: Thanks, this did the job. Also turned out I had to recompile Exim with `WITH_CONTENT_SCAN=yes `

Comment: Also you can reduce host load by excluding of big messages from the scanning - just add one more condition `condition  = ${if <{$message_size}{1M}}` to the `warn` ACL. Most of spam messages are way smaller then 1MB while scanning of such big messages can use too much CPU and RAM.